# LOG transformation

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have data (x,y) with some error bars, and I want to replace each value of y with log(y+1). I tried with Mathematica but it didn't work.

- What is the problem with my code?
- how can I calculate the error bars on a log scale?
- how can I plot these data in a log scale?

```
data = {{2.2, 0.0579}, {6, 0.0624}, {13, 0.0988}, {19, 0.0488}, 
        {31, 0.0956}, {63, 0.0475}, {122, 0.0416}, {141, 0.0325},
        {148, 0.0247}};

dataerror = {0.0150, 0.0117, 0.0241, 0.00975, 0.0229, 0.00650, 
             0.00390, 0.00325, 0.00130};

datalog = {#1, Log@(#2 + 1)} & @@@ data
dataerrorlog = Log[1 + dataerror]
dataplot = ListLogLogPlot@datalog
```

Comment: If you want use `ListLogLogPlot`, you shouldn't transform your data.  Otherwise you transform it twice.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the already given approach, try this:

```
 data/.{x_,y_}->{x,Log(y+1)}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You want the first and second *component* in a list:

```
datalog = {#[[1]], Log@(#[[2]] + 1)} & /@ data
```

Comment: This accomplishes the exact same result as the `datalog = {#1, Log@(#2 + 1)} & @@@ data` snippet in the OP. Perhaps I'm missing your point.